# Did Russell make a grammatical mistake here? "...both that China had ... and had..."

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions, syntactic-analysis, correlative-conjunctions

This is a sentence from Bertrand Russell's work. Notice that the sub-clauses following *both ... and ...* do not exactly match. I wonder if Russell made a grammatical mistake here.

> I was impressed by the facts **both** that China had been able to settle all her other border disputes by negotiation **and** had already, before this last and disastrous flare-up, offered to negotiate with India the border questions which were in dispute between them.

Source: Russell, Bertrand. *Unarmed Victory.* New York: Simon And Schuster, 1963. 102. Print.

Comment: The word 'both' would normally sit after 'that China' and not before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Russell is impressed by two facts:

1. that China settled all her border disputes by negotiation and
2. that it had already (before some "disastrous flare-up" mentioned earlier) offered to negotiate with India the border questions which were in dispute between them.

> Notice that the sub-clauses following *both*... *and* ... do not exactly match.

The only mismatch I see is the slight violation of parallelism due to a missing *that it* before the second fact, i.e. *and that it had already* &c. One may or may not consider it a grammatical error depending on one's conscientiousness.

Comment: I guess this is called the native speaker's privilege. They can take some liberty to trade off grammar for eloquence.

Comment: As a [prescriptivist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_prescription), I am convinced that language is a beautiful system governed by strict and logical rules. I therefore refuse both the native speaker's privilege and the poetic license.

Comment: ESL speakers will appreciate that.

Comment: @Ant_222 I can think of worse *thing's* than poetic license ;)

Comment: What year do you plump for as being the one when all the rules were finalised? Which authority has the final say when they disagree? What do you make of Quirk and Svartvik's conclusion that some constructions are say 20% or 80% acceptable? Do you reject extra-grammatical idioms?

Comment: It is easier to ask those questions in a comment than to answer them in like manner. Shall we continue the discussion in the chat?

Comment: @Ant_222: You are free to refuse any privilege or licence you choose, assuming you are entitled to them. You are not free to deny them to other English-speakers. (And if you want a chat discussion, itr is normal to set up a chatroom yourself).

Comment: @TimLymington, will not the chatroom disappear once I log out of it, if no one else is in and there are fewer than fifteen messages? As to licenses, your viewpoint seems too democratic and liberal—let every man believe what he will rather than seek the objective truth. Did any serious poets, excepting the modern surrealistic ones, ever use the poetic license?

Comment: I repeat that if you have a viewpoint you wish to put forward, you should open a chatroom. You are quite right that nobody else is forced to debate with you; that does not mean you can argue in comments.